# Deserialize JSON string - list/array

Tags: c#, json, serialization

```
   {
       "id":"123", "result":
       {
           "0": { "children_id": "0", "name": "some name" },
           "1": { "children_id": "1", "name": "some other name" }
        }
    }
```

I have this pice of JSON string, how i can deserialize it using:
JSON.NET http://json.codeplex.com ?

I was trying make some class which can hold my json object, but i i don't know how i can hold this "0" and  "1".

```
public class Data
{
    public string children_id  { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Data> result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? `new System.Web.Script.Serialization. JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(string)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This JSON looks badly designed. If you can have multiple children, it should be an array, such as:

```
{
   "id":"123", "result":
   [
       { "children_id": "0", "name": "some name" },
       { "children_id": "1", "name": "some other name" }
   ]
}
```

If you have control over the JSON generation, change that (your current C# code would work in deserialization). If you don't, you are better off deserializing that to a dictionary, which would make your `RootObject` look like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Data> result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier, but i get from one API such JSON string... Using this json online parser: http://json.parser.online.fr/ my example json is parasing like in result field is array. It's no way to parse it in easy way?

Comment: @Yozer Then, try the Dictionary solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Data
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Data> result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Answers containing just code with no explanation are not very useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
JObject jObject = new JObject();
/* jObject = {
   "id":"123", "result":
   {
       "0": { "children_id": "0", "name": "some name" },
       "1": { "children_id": "1", "name": "some other name" }
    }
}
*/
foreach(var g in jObject["result"]){
   switch(g.Key()){
     case 0://do something
            break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say with this answer.